# Eclipse Tomcat server does not start

Tags: java, eclipse, server, tomcat8

**Situation**: I installed JRE 8, and configured Tomcat 8.5 on my Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3).

**Problem** : I added a project and the server console shows server start-up in 41935 ms. But the background process keeps showing "Starting...." This is shown in the ScreenShot below.

Later, the server stops because it times out. Please help me resolve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how this worked, but merely restarting the PC and cleaning Eclipse's Tomcat server solved this issue.

Also, if at any point of time there is a Security alert asking permission to allow Java to access Public or Private networks, check all the boxes.

Comment: May be restarting the server, killed the process that was running on Tomcat server port.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if already an instance of Tomcat server is running on the port(default is 8080). Kindly run below command in command prompt

`netstat -ano`

to list down the list of process and the port they acquire that are running currently and see if there a process running on the Port that your tomcat server is trying to acquire.

If yes, kill it and run the server again

Comment: Ashish, I could not see any ports used by my Tomcat installation (8005,8080 and 8009). Actually the issue somehow got solved by simply restarting my PC and cleaning Eclipse's Tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem with Tomcat 7 (Liferay server), seems to be a compatibility bug in eclipse, I had to change to a lower version of eclipse.